# Websocket port conflict in java desktop applicatioon

Tags: websocket

I need to develop a websocket server in a java desktop application. My problem is that i don't know which port number to use to avoid OS conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any port number above 1024 is typically not reserved for a standard OS use.

You can scan your current system to see what is in use and then pick some number above 3000 that is not currently in use.

See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) for what various ports are known to be used by.

You don't say what OS platform you're running on, but on Windows, you can see what ports are being used for listening with this (run from a command window with administrator privileges):

```
netstat -a¦find /i "listening"
```

On Linux, you can use:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

Port numbers in the 8000 range are very commonly used for custom apps.

Comment: @mmaa - Did this answer your question?  If it did, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and also earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure.